# Christmas Light Route Efficiency

Tags: algorithms, efficiency

This is a real situation <sup><sub>*(I hope it's ok that I post this here. If not, please suggest a better home)*</sub></sup>. I have little knowledge of algorithms, but I know I can use one to solve this problem.

I'm looking for an answer, or an online resource that can help, or an algorithm I should research to help me find the route with the least overlap.

---

I have an enclosed structure with rafters. I want to hang christmas lights inside it, and I'm trying to figure out how to cover all the ceiling beams with lights while minimizing overlap.

Here's a rudimentary schematic of the structure: 
[image: A rudimentary schematic of the structure]

- The pink circles are places I can hang the lights from
- The yellow dots are where the lights should be
- "Start" is the only available electrical outlet
- Each strand of lights is aprox 234 inches (droop and empty sections have been accounted for)

### What is the most efficient path(s) to minimize overlap?

Here's some things to keep in mind:

- Assume I have an infinite number of lights
- The beginning of a strand of lights has a male electric connector. The end has a female.
- The start (male) of one strand must intersect with the end (female) of another strand (for electricity).
- Multiple strands can start from the same point

Here's the XML of the diagram (you can use this in [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mxfile userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" version="7.1.3" editor="www.draw.io" type="device"><diagram id="d7d79c46-3ad7-dd0f-4011-e37531a3d72a" name="Page-1">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</diagram></mxfile>
```

Comment: This is absolutely on-topic. Welcome to the site!

Comment: By the way, just above "start", you have a three-way intersection that isn't a hanging point. Is that a mistake in the diagram?  (If it's deliberate, it's not possible to hang lights on the line segment heading south from that point to the next intersection.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks for the support! In answer to your question, it is deliberate, not a mistake. There is not a hanging spot at the 3-way intersection. What I'll need to do is rely on tension from another hanging spot to  wrap around that corner - I wasn't sure how to show that in the diagram.

Comment: Gotcha. Essentially, you have a bent link around that corner -- you'll probably need to pretend that that's not an intersection, and the mathematics and algorithm should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're trying to solve is called the [route inspection problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem) (a.k.a. Chinese postman problem, from back in the days when it seemed normal to call something "Chinese" because the first person to study it was Chinese).  Good news – there's an efficient algorithm, described in the Wikipedia article.